# ELF, Build-ID, is there a utility to recompute it?

Tags: linux, linker, elf

I came across this useful feature in ELF binaries -- [Build ID](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/FeatureBuildId). ["It ... is (normally) the SHA1 hash over all code sections in the ELF image."](https://gnu.wildebeest.org/blog/mjw/2016/02/02/where-are-your-symbols-debuginfo-and-sources/) One can read it with GNU utility:

```
$ readelf -n /bin/bash
...
Displaying notes found at file offset 0x00000274 with length 0x00000024:
  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000014   NT_GNU_BUILD_ID (unique build ID bitstring)
    Build ID: 54967822da027467f21e65a1eac7576dec7dd821
```

And I wonder if there is an easy way to recompute Build ID yourself? To check if it isn't corrupted etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, I've got an answer from Mark. Since it is an up to date info, I post it here. But basically you guys are right. Indeed there is no tool for computing Build-ID, and the intentions of Build-ID are not (1) identification of the file contents, and not even (2) identification of the executable (code) part of it, but it is for (3) capturing "semantic meaning" of a build, which is the hard bit for formalization. (Numbers are for self-reference.)

Quote from the email:

> > -- "Is there a user tool recomputing the build-id from the file itself, to
> >     check if it's not corrupted/compromised somehow etc?"
> >     If you have time, maybe you could post an answer there?
>
> Sorry, I don't have a stackoverflow account.
>   But the answer is: No, there is no such tool because the precise way a
>   build-id is calculated isn't specified. It just has to be universally
>   unique. Even the precise length of the build-id isn't specified. There
>   are various ways using different hashing algorithms a build-id could be
>   calculated to get a universally unique value. And not all data might
>   (still be) in the ELF file to recalculate it even if you knew how it was
>   created originally.
>
> > Apparently, the intentions of Build-ID changed
> >     since [the Fedora Feature page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/FeatureBuildId) was written about
> >     it.
> >     And people's opinions diverge on what it is now.
> >     Maybe in your answer you could include status of Build-ID and what it is
> >     now as well?
>
> I think things weren't very precisely formulated. If a tool changes the
>   build that creates the ELF file so that it isn't a "semantically
>   identical" binary anymore then it should get a new (recalculated)
>   build-id. But if a tool changes something about the file that still
>   results in a "semantically identical" binary then the build-id stays the
>   same.
>
> What isn't precisely defined is what "semantically identical binary"
>   means. The intention is that it captures everything that a build was
>   made from. So if the source files used to generate a binary are
>   different then you expect different build-ids, even if the binary code
>   produced might happen to be the same.
>
> This is why when calculating the build-id of a file through a hash
>   algorithm you use not just the (allocated) code sections, but also the
>   debuginfo sections (which will contain references to the source file
>   names).
>
> But if you then for example strip the debuginfo out (and put it into a
>   separate file) then that doesn't change the build-id (the file was still
>   created from the same build).
>
> This is also why, even if you knew the precise hashing algorithm used to
>   calculate the build-id, you might not be able to recalculate the
>   build-id. Because you might be missing some of the original data used in
>   the hashing algorithm to calculate the build-id.
>
> Feel free to share this answer with others.
>
> Cheers,
>
> Mark

Also, for people interested in `debuginfo` (linux performance & tracing, anyone?), he mentioned a couple projects for managing them on Fedora:

- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/ParallelInstallableDebuginfo
- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/SubpackageAndSourceDebuginfo

Comment: I'm not sure the part about *"semantically identical binary"* is correct. According to BinUtils' [Debugging Information in Separate Files](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html), the build-id is consistent in the binary *and* the debug files for the binary. The only way to keep them in sync is to ensure a new build gets a new build-id. And a binary could have multiple builds and multiple debug files over time. Reusing a build-id could result in binary and symbol file mismatch.

Comment: @jww, but I don't see a contradiction with what you say. From Mark's answer: "The intention is that it captures everything that a build was made from," -- I conclude that the build-id is a per-build thing. So yes, each build gets a separate build ID. And the hash must include both code and debuginfo, whether it is in a separate file or not. In addition the hash might include some more "semantic" information about the build.

Comment: I should note that Mark is "Mark Wielaard" whose blog is referenced in the question.

Answer (score 3):

The build ID is not a hash of the program, but rather a unique identifier for the build, and is to be considered just a "unique blob" — at least at some point it used to be defined as a hash of timestamp and absolute file path, but that's not a guarantee of stability either.

Comment: ok, but it seems they changed it at some point. [In this email](http://cygwin.com/ml/binutils/2008-11/msg00214.html) Roland McGrath says: "The purpose of the build ID is to uniquely identify the binary created by a build so that its ID only matches that of a semantically identical binary," -- so it's not just a random blob. Not sure how the things are today though. [The Fedora's feature page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/FeatureBuildId) is from 2007..

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder if there is an easy way to recompute Build ID yourself?

No, there isn't, *by design*.

The page you linked to itself links to the original [description](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/FeatureBuildId) of what build-id is and what it's usable for. That pages says:

```
But I'd like to specify it explicitly as being a unique identifier good
only for matching, not any kind of checksum that can be verified against 
the contents.

(There are external general means for content verification, and I don't 
think debuginfo association needs to do that.)
```

Additional complications are: the linker [can take any of](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html):

```
--build-id
--build-id=sha1
--build-id=md5
--build-id=0xhexstring
```

So the build id is *not necessarily* an sha1 sum to begin with.

Comment: yep, but the Fedora page is "Last updated: 2007-10-04", the article I refer to is from 2016. Also in [this thread from 2008](https://cygwin.com/ml/binutils/2008-11/msg00197.html) the Fedora people [mention their tool](https://cygwin.com/ml/binutils/2008-11/msg00211.html) recomputing build-id.
It seems the full build-id calculation and its' intentions are [described by Roland McGrath here](https://cygwin.com/ml/binutils/2008-11/msg00214.html). I don't know what's the status now - any pointers are welcome.
A meaningful ID is a good thing for a binary and would be a very useful feature.